# Can not change the value of a combobox in an user control from another form

Tags: vb.net, autocad

I have an user control in Autocad that makes drawings based on certain criteria.
From this user control, another form can be opened which is used to fill in specific data.
When i try to automatically change the Combobox in the User Control with data from the Form, it gives the error:

> Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

Now I have looked this up on the internet, but I can not seem to apply the solutions given.
My situation is as follows:

```
Partial Public Class Partial Public Class User_Control
    Private Form1 As New Form_Something
  private sub button1_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    Form1.show()
  End sub
End Class
```

This User Control has got a Combobox, lets name it Combobox1.  Now when i change a value on Form_Something, Combobox1 must change as well.
So I've got the following code in Form1:

```
Partial public class Form_Something
    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BT_Apply.Click
       User_Control.Combobox1.text = "Apples"
    End sub
End class
```

This gives the mentioned error.
Can someone please help me resolve this issue, because I'd like to do this with multiple comboboxes/labels etc.

Comment: Notice how you have to refer to a specific `ComboBox` to affect that control rather than just the `ComboBox` class? Makes sense, given that you could have multiple `ComboBoxes`. Why, then, do you think that you can just refer to your `User_Control` class and affect a specific instance of that type? If you could do that and you had multiple instances, what would you expect to happen? You need to refer to the actual instance you want to affect, not just its type.

Comment: Probably need to make sure you've set the Modifiers Property on ComboBox1 in FormSomething correctly as well

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney, So when I refer to the User control from the form, I have to refer to a specific instance of the User Control or a specific instance of the combobox?

Comment: @Hursey Thank you, I've already set the Modifier to `public` but it did not help the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show you more intuitively, I changed the `BorderStyle` of `UserControl1` here. You can change or comment it as needed.

I have commented on some key parts of the code, please let me know if you are still confused.

If my post helps to resolve your issue, please click the "Mark as Answer" of that post. By marking a post as Answered or Helpful, you help others find the answer faster.

The results are as follows:
[image]

My code are as follows:

1.`Form1` code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MyUserControl.ComboBox1.Text = "Apples"
    End Sub
End Class
```

2.`UserControl1` code:

```
Public Class UserControl1

    Private Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.Text = "Apple"
        Me.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    End Sub

    Dim myForm As Form
    Dim btn As Button
    Dim txtbox As TextBox

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        myForm = New Form With {.Text = "myForm"}
        btn = New Button With {.Text = "Save", .Height = 30, .Width = 60, .Top = 100, .Left = 150}
        txtbox = New TextBox With {.Text = "", .Height = 20, .Width = 100, .Top = 100, .Left = 20}

        myForm.Controls.Add(btn)
        myForm.Controls.Add(txtbox)

        myForm.Show() 'Open dialog in modeless window

        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Btn_Click
    End Sub

    Sub Btn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.ComboBox1.Text = txtbox.Text 'This step is important!
        myForm.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I have to rebuild my forms a bit, but i'll manage. Thank you so much, this has been bugging me for a while, in future projects, I can build the codes the right way from the start.